# Unity - Across the wall

Tags: unity, collision-detection, physics, navmesh

I have a problem here.

I animated my main character and is working. It walks run and jump however it goes across walls and ground.

As in every single video I watch in unity tutorials I put a navigation static in every single wall and game object. However the main character still go across them as thin air

The main character has a rigid body and collider as does the  the wall and other game objects

I really don't understand 
I don't really understand what i did wrong or what I miss? Script ? other things I am not aware?The Nav Mesh Agent?[image: This is the inspect of the main character![This is the inspect of the wall(s)] ][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26EUK.png)

I really hope someone can help me

Thanks in advance

CL

Answer (score 3):

Read up on the [`IsTrigger`](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-BoxCollider.html) variable. Specifically:

> **Is Trigger**: If enabled, this Collider is used for triggering events,
>   and is ignored by the physics engine.

Answer (score 0):

As Byte56 already told you have `IsTrigger` checkbox turned in your wall. You need to turn it off, so that it can collide with any other object which has collider in it. If you do not want your wall to collide with some other object, you can put both wall and other object in separate layer and then can turn off collision between those layers by going to `Edit->Project Settings ->Physics`. However this will turn off any `OnTriggerEnter` (or any trigger related call) between these layers too.